# ssh | how to handle errors for multiple commands

Tags: bash, ssh

Hi I am aware that we can check the status of previous command by     $? following scenario is not working for me

```
ssh $USER@$HOST bash -c "'
echo "Preparing list of files to be transferred...."
rsync <something>
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "remote error occurred"
    exit 1
fi
echo "end"
'"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "remote error occurred"
    exit 1
else
    echo "remote did not return any error"
    exit 0
fi
```

output that I get is

```
Preparing list of files to be transferred....
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]
end
remote did not return any error
```

Any suggestion on how to handle errors on ssh for multiple commands ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the answer

```
rsync <something>
if [ \$? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "remote error occurred"
    exit 1
fi
```

Adding a backslash does the trick.